# Remove duplication in OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional relationship using a JoinTable (with an OrderColumn)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have a OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional relationship using a join table. The children are in a List and are ordered.

Here's the setup:

Parent:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name="parent_child",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="child_id")
)
@OrderColumn(name="child_order")
public List<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
}
```

Child:

```
@ManyToOne
public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

Here's my issue: The parent table is as expected, but here are the child and parent_child tables:

child:

```
int8 id,
int8 parent_id <---
```

parent_child:

```
int8 parent_id, <---
int8 child_id,
int8 child_order
```

There's duplication with the parent_id - it's specified in the join table and in the child table which means that it's possible to call parent.getChildren().get(0).getParent() and end up with a different parent than you started with, which should be impossible (and I'd like that to be enforced at the database level).

The only way I can see to fix this is to use a join column in the child, and not use a join table at all. But I don't like that because then I have to move the order to the child, plus the hibernate docs say that a JoinColumn with OneToMany should be avoided (but they don't really say why).

Is there any other way of getting rid of this duplication/possible inconsistency? I.e. some way of having the child know its parent by using the data from the join table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works. Note the use of JoinColumn

```
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @OrderColumn(name="child_order")
   public List<Child> getChildren() {
         return children;
   }
```

child

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn("parent_id")
   public Parent getParent() {
       return parent;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> There's duplication with the parent_id - it's specified in the join table and in the child table which means that it's possible to call parent.getChildren().get(0).getParent() and end up with a different parent than you started with

I don't understand how can that be possible, when a child can have only one parent. There should be one and only one record int database for a given parent-child tuple and the child will never exists in any other tuple of parent-child. Ofcourse the parent will be repeated in the parent_child table but never will a child be repeated. Have you specified the foreign key constraints on the database tables? Use the mappedBy element on the getParent() method.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to a similar question in [Constraint violation in Hibernate unidirectional OneToMany mapping with JoinTable and OrderColumn when removing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022509/constraint-violation-in-hibernate-unidirectional-onetomany-mapping-with-jointable)

Please have a look
I think your constraints on your association table is bad and incompatible with the principle of a List.