# @OrderColumn generates a request to update the primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I use a list. The list is comprised of a compound primary key which is also used for sorting the list.
The problem is that if I delete an element in the list (key compound),
annotation `@OrderColumn` generates a request to update a primary key, and the cost rises an exception of type:

```
[26-05-2011 10:34:18:835] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000  
[26-05-2011 10:34:18:835] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  -Duplicate  entry '10-10' for key 'PRIMARY'  
[26-05-2011 10:34:18:835] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Here is the definition of the mapping :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "chapter_item", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
@OrderColumn(name="iorder")
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

Here is the update query where I have a problem:

```
Hibernate: 
update
    chapter_item 
set
    item_id=? 
where
    chapter_id=? 
    and iorder=?
```

I wonder if this is a known bug, and if anyone has a solution?

Comment: 1) Have you created equals & hashCode in the Item class? 2) Is it a 2-way association? (from your class to Item) and 3) Please include the code you are using to delete the item.

Comment: Can you provide us your implementation of Chapter and Item?

Comment: You can't use *cascade=CascadeType.ALL*

Comment: The error states that your UPDATE query results in a duplicate primary-key which cannot be allowed in the database .. this either happens if the update set an existing primary-key to another record, or if the update condition apply to more than 1 record.

Comment: I think this already got answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022509/constraint-violation-in-hibernate-unidirectional-onetomany-mapping-with-jointabl
It's not exactly the same mapping but the problem with Hibernate seems to be the same.

Comment: Show your database structure including primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @OrderColumn, following documentation is found at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

> Specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a
>   list. The persistence provider is responsible for maintaining the
>   order upon retrieval and in the database. The persistence provider is
>   responsible for updating the ordering upon flushing to the database to
>   reflect any insertion, deletion, or reordering affecting the list.

So we see that the persistence provider i.e. hibernate is responsible for updating the column named `iorder`. It is also said that:

> The OrderColumn annotation is specified on a OneToMany or ManyToMany
>   relationship or on an element collection. The OrderColumn annotation
>   is specified on the side of the relationship that references the
>   collection that is to be ordered. The order column is not visible as
>   part of the state of the entity or embeddable class.

Please take note of the sentence that says:

> The order column is not visible as part of the state of the entity or
>   embeddable class.

So, may I suggest you to consider not selecting the column `iorder` for `@OrderColumn` since it is a part of your `composite key` and hibernate is sure to update this value when you delete or insert an element in list (`List<Item>`).

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one option could be change the order annotation and use:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "chapter_item", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =     "chapter_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns =  {@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
@org.hibernate.annotations.Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = ItemComparator)
public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}
```

https://dzone.com/articles/sorting-collections-hibernate

Check performance solution because maybe is too slow for big amount of data, and if you can share if was a possible solution would be great to know